# shopware 5 cloaking mask affiliate link

Tags: .htaccess, masking, affiliate, shopware, cloaking

Shopware has its own affiliate programm http://en.community.shopware.com/_detail_1172.html?_ga=1.3316085.419512806.1450178118

Right now some partners link from their wordpress site to shopware and they cloak their partner url with some plugin for wordpress. But when they head forward to it the url is something like: http://www.myshopware.com/myitem?sPartner=kelkoo

The shopowner wishes to mask/cloak the url so that there is no sPartner=kelkoo

So kind of the other way around...
It's about 150 Partners right now and maybe going to be more.

The question is, doing it via .htaccess or maybe a different way? (I think a plugin would be the best, which writes into/enhances the .htaccess when adding a new partner.)

Answer (score 0):

Should the link completelly masked till the registration or just the link in the website ?

Comment: I guess the link should be completely masked till the registration. If i am right, I think the variable sPartner is saved to a cookie.